# Updating a cell when a new form is submitted

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I am trying to pull scores from one google sheet to another, and I want this information to update when a new form is submitted by the same person.

Score page
[image]

Summary Page

[image]

[Link to sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PD3XbKs-NUaU3OgotpQuWBxkrmtrkBDkw6hzzC4Zpt4/edit#gid=1994998575)

[Link to Google Form](https://forms.gle/RBSAbDo1WnJVyQp58)

Comment: The sample spreadsheet gives "Access denied."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in cell `Summary!B3`:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    vlookup( 
      A3:A, 
      sort('Colors'!B2:N, 'Colors'!A2:A, false), 
      columns('Colors'!B2:N), 
      false 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

Comment: It returned a blank cell. Don't I need to reference the sheet called colors?

Comment: Replace the instances of `'Colors'` in the formula with the name of the sheet where the responses are. I cannot see your real sheet names, because the sample spreadsheet continues to give "Access denied."